# How to handle special characters in URLs while using \href

Tags: hyperref, symbols, urls

Special characters like `%` throw `href` off. What package, if any, gives a work around? Would there be a side effect to changing the URLs  from `%` to `\%`?

EDIT
On a second try, on a different computer, I do not see any problems except that TeXworks editor does treat items in a `href` after `%` as a comment (and actually so does this web site!) On the first computer I got an error message too. I'll post if I can reproduce it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
% the original URL
{\href{http://wims.unice.fr/wims/wims.cgi?session=1I6D03A2E6.5&+lang=en&+module=tool%2Fanalysis%2Ffunction.en}{ App 0.1 }}
% the modified URL
{\href{http://wims.unice.fr/wims/wims.cgi?session=1I6D03A2E6.5&+lang=en&+module=tool\%2Fanalysis\%2Ffunction.en}{ App 0.1 }}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If you are using `\href` from the `url` package then `%` is OK so long as the command is not in the argument of another command (that is, the same rules as for `\verb`)

Comment: What I see is that TeX treats % as the beginning of a comment even if it is inside a URL address handled by href. I just manually insert a slash behind each. I must be missing something.

Comment: Yes, a mimimal example

Comment: LaTeX does not define `\href` so if you have such a macro it must be defined somewhere, but you have not given any indication of what definition you are using. url package is a common one, but hyperref and many classes also define similar but different versions.

Comment: 1. Using `%2` indeed works with hyperref 6.82p, but (if my memories are correct) there are older versions of the package where it does not work. (`\listfiles` in the preamble of the document will list all files with version info at the end of the log file.)
2. Why don't you use `/` instead of `%2F`? That should work with all versions of hyperref, url or whatsoever.
3. Also UltraEdit (13.20a) treats everything after a `%` as comment, but tex.SE is at least so smart to treat text after `\%` not as comment.

Comment: Yes, I would say tex.SE is a smart place! It should be acknowledged in a Hollywood movie. Good will Hunting 2, perhaps.

Comment: This question can be closed.